# XSL choose styling text AND td

Tags: css, xslt

I'm using an XSLT choose to style the contents of a cell. For some reason, it's styling both the text and the td. If I then try and recolor the `<td>` with CSS it just makes it disappear altogether.

```
<td>
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@status = 'OPEN'">
                <xsl:text>color: limegreen;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>color: red;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@status" />
</td>
```

I just want it to color the `value-of select`, not the cell border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your above code you are coloring the whole `<td>`.
If you want to style only the text, apply it on a `<span>` (or something) like this:

```
<td>
    <span>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@status = 'OPEN'">
                    <xsl:text>color: limegreen;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>color: red;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="@status" />
    </span>
</td>
```

This should color only the text and not the border.